# Enabling Markdown for the documentation property of completionItem?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm writing my first language extension for VS Code and I find the documentation to be rather difficult to follow. This is of course not helped by me being inexperienced with writing extensions for VS Code, so here I am.

As the subject says, I want to enable Markdown for the *documentation* property of my *completionItem* but after literally hours of searching and reading I still don't know how to do this.

The VS Code Language API tells me to use *MarkdownString* but VS Code knows nothing about *MarkdownString*. If I try to reference the deprecated *MarkedString* the VS Code tooltip documentation for it tells me to use *MarkupContent* instead.

If I use *MarkupContent* the tooltip tells me that...

> A MarkupContent literal represents a string value which content is interpreted base on its kind flag.

(As an aside, the example on how to construct the string is incorrect which doesn't inspire confidence).

None the less, it's easy enough to figure out the problem with the example and I can implement it in my code:

```
const markdown: MarkupContent = {
  kind: MarkupKind.Markdown,
  value: ""
};
```

The value is blank as I dynamically define it depending on what item we're "completing."

I have a list of suggestions that I index using the item.data value sent by the *onCompletion* function:

```
const suggestions = [
{
      label: "DATEADD",
      kind: CompletionItemKind.Function,
      insertText: "@DATEADD(${1:<date>}, ${2:<days>})",
      insertTextFormat: InsertTextFormat.Snippet,
      documentation:
        "Adds a specified number of days to the given date, returning the result as a *yyyyMMdd* date.",
},
    ...
```

I use the *documentation* property as it's already present to set the value of *markdown.value*:

```
markdown.value = suggestions[item.data].documentation;
```

After this I assign *markdown* to *suggestions[item.data].documentation*:

```
suggestions[item.data].documentation = markdown;
```

This doesn't work though and I get the error "Type 'MarkupContent' is not assignable to type 'string'.", despite the documentation saying that "A MarkupContent literal represents a string value..."

By now I'm certain that I'm doing all of this ass backwards and that there should be a simple flag or property that I can set to tell VS Code that I'm using Markdown for the documentation instead of jumping through all these hoops.

Any tips, tricks, pointers, or straws I can grasp for are more than welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`CompletionItem::documentation?: string | MarkdownString`

> A human-readable string that represents a doc-comment.

- create a [MarkdownString](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#MarkdownString)
- assign this object to `suggestions[item.data].documentation`

Comment: This isn't helpful. I mentioned that MarkdownString isn't recognized by VS Code, and any attempt to import it gives me an error:

'"vscode-languageserver/node"' has no exported member named 'MarkdownString'. Did you mean 'MarkedString'?

Comment: @MartinEdelius you don't need to import it it is part of `vscode`

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you but it isn't included for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against this for a while more I got it to work by converting a *MarkupContent* variable to an *unknown* and then a *string*:

```
  const markdown: MarkupContent = {
    kind: MarkupKind.Markdown,
    value: suggestions[item.data].documentation,
  };

  suggestions[item.data].documentation = <string>(<unknown>markdown);
  return suggestions[item.data];
```

This still feels like I'm jumping through hoops but at least it works.